# Writing arrays to text file in particular fomat

Tags: python, numpy

I'm new to python and struggling to get the below format.

I have 3 arrays of same size. `a=[1,2,3]`, `b=[4,5,6]` and `c=[7,8,9]`. I want to write them to a text file from the second line. The first line has already some text with three columns, a, b and c. I want the output to look like

```
a  b  c
1  4  7
2  5  6
3  8  9
```

I tried using `numpy.savetxt('test.txt', (a,b,c), '%s', delimiter='\t')`. But it does not give the format I want. 
My actual data will contain 14 columns with each column having 1200 values.
Can someone please help me?

Comment: To be clear: you want the absolute spacing in your file? Define your format.

Comment: I am not sure i understood your question. I want the data more like a table form with rows and columns with one whitespace both horizontally and vertically.

Comment: Do your values have more than one character?

Comment: the actual values are between 0 to 100 with two decimals. 0.00 to 99.99

Comment: I see, what I'm trying to understand is, what's important to you? Is it the format, you can later parse it again? Or its just the way it looks?  There will some shifting will occur while you're writing because of the difference in character lengths. If that's not a problem, you can simply use for loops to write each column and row. And it will become simply a csv file.

Comment: I will later read this file in a different program and pick up values from rows and columns as needed. To do this, I believe, I should have proper formatting of rows and columns.

Comment: Yes you are right, I answered below a code to serve your needs.

Answer (score 1):

If parsing later is important to you, I must suggest writing csv files.

```
 import csv
 data = [['a', 'b', 'c'],
         ['1', '2', '3'],
         ['4', '5', '6'],
         ['7', '8', '9']]

 with open('testing.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
     csv = csv.writer(file, delimiter=',')
     csv.writerows(data)
```

If you use csv, you can later parse and read your file anywhere you want. Even in sql data importing.

Answer (score 0):

The simpler way is just to loop through your elements and write exactly what you want. You can customize it as much as you want this way:

```
col_headers = ['a','b','c']
a=[1,2,3]
b=[4,5,6]
c=[7,8,9]
columns = [a,b,c]
data = [col_headers]+zip(*columns)
separator = '\t' # or ', ' for example 
with open('yourfile.txt','w') as fout:
    for line in data:
        fout.write( separator.join( map(str,line) ) )
        fout.write('\n')
```

Answer (score -2):

Thanks for your help!
I tried this and seems to work well in the format I want.

```
f=open('testing.txt,'w')
temp= str(1) + '\t' + str(2) + '\t' + str(3) + '\n'
f.write(val)
```

Use for loop for the second row and so on.
This writes to a text file with 1 row and three columns. Later I can load this file and pick up values I want.

Comment: This will work fine. I still recommend using csv, which is basically the same thing but a file format will be recognized by any data system.